# Handling Exceptions from spring context

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-ioc

How can i handle exceptions from `Spring context` .
Consider the context

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe" />
    <property name="user" value="abc" />
    <property name="password" value="abc" />    
</bean>

<bean id="abc" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/abc-persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

And am loading context in main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext  applicationContext = null;
    try {
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/test.xml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caugtht " + e);
    }
}
```

Lets say database is down .now when i load context exceptions are not caught in catch block. Is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: Did you try with Throwable as well?

Comment: yes tried throwable as well

Comment: You create an exception handler that handles exception. Check this article https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I think its more relevant to MVC. Is there any handler for non-mvc Spring applications?

Comment: @pppavan  did you find a way to handle this exception? I am looking for the same